# Create cxx file for hxx file in C++

Tags: c++, oop, header-files

I have a file GetL.hxx

```
#ifndef GetL_included
#define GetL_included
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class GetL
{
 public:
    virtual int getWidth();
};
#endif //GetL_include
```

Here the class GetL contains only one virtual function and thus is a abstract class. How can i create .cxx file for this .hxx file?

Comment: Use "add new file" in your IDE or create a new file using your favorite text editor and add it to your build script...  or do you mean "what should I put in the source file"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an abstract class. An abstract class contains a pure virtual function. For example , if you wanted to make your class abstract you could put `virtual int getWidth() = 0;` which would force the `getWidth()` function to be defined in a derived class.

It's probably also worth mentioning that it's not a good idea to put `using` statements in a header file. It pollutes the current namespace unnecessarily and can lead to naming conflicts.

Comment: if this is not an abstract class and function is `virtual int getWidth()` then how can i write the .cxx file.

Comment: You can just write it like a normal class file. In this case the `virtual` keyword merely means that a derived class has the option of overriding that particular function.

Comment: You mean that in GetL.cxx i should give a body to getWidth() function?

Answer (score 2):

If your class is supposed to be abstract you should declare `getWidth()` to be abstract.

Like this `virtual int getWidth() = 0;`. That makes the function pure virtual, which is a requirement for the class being abstract.

Then there is no need to create a .cxx file, since there is no implementation to go with your totally abstract class.

Only if you have more methods, of which not all are pure virtuals would you be required to create an implementation file. As long as the class consists of only pure virtual functions you do not need to create an implementation.

**Edit:** To provide an implementation, create a new file called GetL.cxx

```
#include "GetL.hxx"

int GetL::getWidth() {
    // Insert implementation here
}
```

Depending on your IDE and project settings you may need to `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of this implementation file. Note that if you provide an implementation your class is no longer abstract, and you must not use `= 0` in your method declaration.