# Create Source file for Header file

Tags: c++

I have a file GetL.hxx

```
#ifndef GetL_included
#define GetL_included
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class GetL
{
 public:
    virtual int getWidth();
};
#endif //GetL_include
```

Here the class GetL contains only one virtual function. what should i put in source file i.e. in GetL.cxx

Comment: You should have `#endif // !GetL_included` at the end.

Comment: @AdeYU can u please explain the difference

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create cxx file for hxx file in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390953/create-cxx-file-for-hxx-file-in-c)

Comment: @user you should add an exclamation mark in the bottom comments. Because the code above it is *if not defined GetL_included*  And the typo need fixing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include "GetL.hxx"

int GetL::getWidth() {
  // your code goes here
}
```

By the way, having `using namespace std;` in a header file [is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452759/367273).

Comment: how can i `#include <iostream>` without having `using namespace std`??

Comment: i want to create a virtual method so that GetL class can be inherited and getWidth method overridden. If i give implementation like that it will defeat the reason because of which i created it..

Comment: If you `#include <iostream>` without `using namespace std`, you refer to the contents of iostream as within the std namespace. For example, you use `std::cout`, not just `cout`. This avoids polluting the global namespace. Nonetheless, you aren't using anything from the iostream header file so you don't need to include it.